# reduce multibox_model size and speed up the model

Tags: tensorflow

I'm currently using the TF Detect demo,finding it too large for android apk because the multibox_model is 18Mb large.Also it takes about two seconds to recognize a human in camera using my nexus4 device. Is there any method to reduce the size of model and speed up ? or other better model for mobile?

Comment: You can use a different model which is smaller.

Comment: Any advice？for human detecting